# Multiple div in class

Tags: css

So I have the following html and css.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a"> A </div>
  <div class="b"> B </div>
  <div class="c"> C </div>
  <div class="d"> D </div>
  <div class="e"> E </div>
  <div class="F"> F </div>
</div>

<style>
   .parent .a{display:none;}
   .parent .b{display:none;}
   .parent .c{display:none;}
   .parent .d{display:none;}
   .parent .e{display:none;}
</style>
```

In this case, how can I simplify the css so that I don't have to repeat the same code 5 times?

EDIT: I should have been more clear. Not all of the elements are hidden. Only a selection of the classes are hidden in "parent" (class="f" is not hidden)

Thanks

Comment: `.parent div{display:none}`

Comment: or also `.parent { display: none }`since all the elements inside are hidden

Comment: Or to hide all immediate children `.parent > * {display: none;}`

Comment: EDIT: I should have been more clear. Not all of the elements are hidden. Only a selection of the classes are hidden in "parent" (class="f" is not hidden)

Comment: Are you able to modify the HTML? The best way would be to add a common class to all the elements you have to hide, and hide apply the `display: none` to that specific class. Unfortunately, if you cannot modify the HTML and add a common class you're not having much of an option than to repeat yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options.

### Option 1:

Like @Akshay commented, you can do:

```
.parent div {
    display: none;
}
```

And every single `div` inside of it will get `display: none`;

### Option 2:

You can also do:

```
.parent >div {
   display: none;
}
```

And it will only target first level `divs`.

### Option 3:

Also you can add a specific class to hide elements.

For example : `hidden`

```
.parent .hidden {
   display: none;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a hidden"> A </div>
  <div class="b hidden"> B </div>
  <div class="c hidden"> C </div>
  <div class="d hidden"> D </div>
  <div class="e hidden"> E </div>
  <div class="F"> F </div>
</div>
```

This way F will still show and all the others are hidden.

### Option 4:

If you want all the content of the parent to be hidden, you can also give the `parent` the `display: none`.. Like this:

```
.parent {
   display: none;
}
```

This way the parent and all the children are hidden.

There are a lot more options .. but these are only some examples.

Comment: Think he does not want additional classes. The PO wants to simplify it.

Comment: EDIT: I should have been more clear. Not all of the elements are hidden. Only a selection of the classes are hidden in "parent" (class="f" is not hidden)

Comment: Then the best option is the option 3, where you add an extra class. That way later if you want to manipulate it with javascript or even css, it's easier to remove the class. And the css is targeting one class only, keeping it simple.

Comment: yeah, i will have to modify the backend html file but that should be doable. Thanks Joel! =)

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this:

```
.parent {
    display: none;
}
```

OR

```
.parent .A .B .C .D .E{
        display: none;
    }
```

Reference :http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp

Comment: This is pretty incorrect and does nothing of what PO wanted. 1st would hide `.parent`, second would hide nothing.

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Comment: `.parent .A .B .C .D .E` Doesn't exist. That means a .E element in a .D element in a .C element..... and so on

Answer (score 0):

if your want all the child-element dispaly:none,you can just set the parent

```
.parent {display:none}
```

if your want to set special element,special attribute

```
.parent * {code..}
.parent div {code...}
```

that is depends on your situation

Answer (score 0):

You can give the style property to the parent div to simplify the css

> .parent {display:none}

or if you want apply only to div inside the .parent class

> .parent div {display:none;}

Answer (score 0):

If visible/hidden DIVs depend on their position, you can use `:nth-child()` :

```
.parent > div{
    display:none;
}
.parent > div:nth-child(6) {
    display:block;
}
```

[Exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/gyypc1d7/)

---

`Even` elements

```
.parent > div{
    display:none;
}
.parent > div:nth-child(even) {
    display:block;
}
```

[Exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/ohtb8ehy/)

---

Every 3 elements starting at the 2nd one :

```
.parent > div{
    display:none;
}
.parent > div:nth-child(3n+2) {
    display:block;
}
```

[Exemple](https://jsfiddle.net/xsd7t5hy/)

---

> [Documentation](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/)

Answer (score 0):

I can offer you this approach:

1. Hide all children, than target those you want to be visible:

```css
.parent > div {
 display: none;
}
.parent > div.f {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="a">hide A</div>
    <div class="b">hide B</div>
    <div class="c">hide C</div>
    <div class="d">hide D</div>
    <div class="e">hide E</div>
    <div class="f">I'm visible</div>
</div>
```

That would be good if you have only couple of visible items.